# $x^2=1$ has more than 2 distinct solutions in $\mathbb Z/ n\mathbb Z$.

Tags: number-theory

Consider a positive odd $n$ which is not a power of a single prime, i.e, $n$ is odd and is not of the form $p^r$ for some prime $p$.

Show that the equation $x^2=1$ has more than 2 distinct solutions in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. What about when $n$ is even?

My thoughts are that when n is even, we have two solutions, namely $\bar1$ and -$\bar1$. Should I use the isomorphism to break this into two smaller rings?

Additionally, assume we know how to factor $n$ explicitly. Then how can we show it's easy to find a solution to $x^2=\bar1$ with $x\neq \bar1$ or -$\bar1$

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Which isomorphism are you speaking of?

Comment: I was thinking about $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z $ ----> $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$ but now that I think more, we won't be able to do this since we don't know the factorization.

Comment: If $n$ is not a prime power then it is a product of multiple primes, $p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_s^{e_s}$. You can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem with that fact.

Answer (score 0):

$n = a b$ and $(a,b)=1$ ,since its not prime nor a prime power, think about the four numbers

$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ which are

$x_1 = 1 \mod a $ and $x_1 = 1\mod b$

$x_2 = -1 \mod a$ and $x_2 = -1 \mod b$

$x_3 = 1 \mod a$ and $x_3 =-1 \mod b$

$x_4 = -1 \mod a$ and $x_4 = 1 \mod b$

easy to prove that $x^2_1 ,x^2_2 ,x^2 _3 ,x^2_4 = 1 \mod ab$

Done.

Comment: If we do this, then how do we find a counterexample for when n is even? I tried n=6 such that a=2 and b=3, but to no avail. I can't figure out a formula to find where this fails.

Comment: $1= -1 $ when $a=2$